# syntax for static and scope data in a same ng-click param

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This href

```
href="http://url.com.php?id={{post.id}}"
```

become, without url

```
ng-click="createTab(post.id);"
```

what is the correct syntax for include url ? i tried (and many others)

```
ng-click="createTab('http://url.com.php?id={{post.id}}');"
```

but i have {{post.id}} in plain text in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate!

```
ng-click="createTab('http://url.com.php?id=' + post.id);"
```

`ng-click` is an Angular directive, so you omit the `{{}}` and add the variable to your string parameter